# OnClick change ZIndex of another element

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, z-index

```
<Button BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent" Grid.Column="0" Padding="0" Grid.Row="0" Focusable="False" Width="Auto" >
    <Button.Content>
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Margin="0,0,6,0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Filter" Foreground="#FFC0B6D1" FontFamily="Segoe UI Semibold" FontSize="14" />
            <Image Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,4,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="6" Width="12" Source="/SizeStream.WPF;component/Assets/filter-arrow-light.png"/>
        </Grid>
    </Button.Content>
    <Button.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UIElement.PreviewMouseDown">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:0.00" Storyboard.TargetName="FiltersPanel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Panel.ZIndex" From="2" To="3" Duration="0:0:00.2"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Button.Triggers>
</Button>
```

I have this button. For it I've added `EventTrigger` which must change ZIndex of element with name `FiltersPanel`:

```
<Grid Margin="0,0,0,0" Panel.ZIndex="2" ClipToBounds="False" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Name="FiltersPanel">...</Grid>
```

But Onclick i get unhandled Exception and I don't know why and what todo.

Comment: Can you explain your exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change animation to `Int32Animation` and not use attached property `Panel.ZIndex` in this animation, just rename to `ZIndex`. So code looks like that.

```
<Int32Animation BeginTime="0:0:0.00" Storyboard.TargetName="FiltersPanel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ZIndex" From="2" To="3" Duration="0:0:00.2"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what i expect.